# Binding the IsSelected property of ListBoxItem to DataContext of Itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an ListBox with an Itemssource defined:

```
 <ListBox
    x:Name="ModuleListBox"
    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
           <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
       </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ListBox>
```

My MenuItems ViewModel implements the INotifyChanged Interface and looks like:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected 
    { 
        get { return isSelected; }  
        set { SetProperty(ref isSelected, value); } 
    }
}
```

The ViewModel of the View where my Listbox lives in looks like:

```
public class ShellViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems
    {
        get { return menuItems; }
        set { SetProperty(ref menuItems, value); }
    }
}
```

My Question is how can i bind the IsSelected Property of the ListBoxItem to the Selected property of MenuItemViewModel item object?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now? You didn't provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces a problem, and you haven't stated any specific problem exists. There's nothing obviously wrong with the little bit of code you did post. So, what's your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="ModuleListBox"
    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
           <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext.IsSelected}" />
       </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the selected item prop of listbox

```
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMenuItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Also create SelectedMenuItem in your ShellViewModel

SelectedItem from ListBox is not Boolean, so if you really want to bind it to menuitem then you have to write your IValueConvertor.